# Rich Text Editor for Vaadin with custom Rich Text Elements

Tags: vaadin, richtextbox, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, html-editor

I have a template document where elements in the document will need to be substituted by the application later in the process.  I want to use a Rich Text Editor for the user to type the template text they wish to use.  For example, the text might look like this.

"This is a notification to `USERNAME` that you have received mail.  An email was sent to `USER-EMAIL`.  Contact `ADMIN-NAME` at `ADMIN-EMAIL` if assistance is needed".

This is a crude example.  For anyone using the interface, `USERNAME`, `USER-EMAIL`, `ADMIN-NAME`, `ADMIN-EMAIL` would be custom buttons in the Rich Text Editor that the user could click on to add to the Rich Text Area as they type.  The raw text in the Rich Text Area could be retrieved and parsed to replace the Rich Text Elements with the intended value later in the application.

Is there a way with a Vaadin component or any type of Rich Text Editor that would provide this ability?

Comment: You can use https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymce-for-flow as the RichTextEditor but I'm not aware of any framework that does what you want to do. So you probably add a click listener to the button and add the place holder to the text

Comment: There is Enhanced RTE component in Directory https://vaadin.com/directory/component/enhanced-rich-text-editor, which has feature to lock texts as read only segments, which could fit you. See demo https://incubator.app.fi/enhanced-rich-text-editor-demo/enhanced-rich-text-editor

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Your suggestion is probably the best choice and was something I considered.

I looked at the enhanced-rich-test-editor and can't find the text locking.  Must be blind or something.

Still, I don't know why this concept is not available.  Whether business or personal, there should be many out there who would want this functionality.